# install Ubuntu from USB key on a windows 10 PC

Tags: usb

I am new to Linux and trying to install it "on an external USB key".

I read and followed the official instructions carefully on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/
but this does not seem very detailed.

I downloaded and installed the installer provided at pendrivelinux.com, "linking" it to the ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64 file that was on my downloads folder (on my C drive).

I can see that some new files appeared on my USB key. Then what should I do ? No menu or windows appears. The official documentation mentions I might need to press F12 if no menu appears. I tried to press F12 but nothing. No menu.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

when are you pressing F12? It should be after the BIOS loaded and before the Windows 10 boots. (in other words right after you pressed the power button of your computer)

Comment: OK. I tried pressing F12 just after powering on my computer. Nothing happens. I just land on the windows 10.

Comment: I know what the issue was. I had to turn off Fast Boot, as explained on this very good blog. http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-create-ubuntu-1510-usb-drive.html

You only have to do this on computers with a UEFI bootloader.

In order to speed up the boot time, Windows prevents booting from a USB until it has fully loaded. 

This obviously prevents Ubuntu booting from the USB drive which is of course a major issue.